# ターミナル起動時に "-bash: :i: command not found" と表示される

Tags: bash

以下の画像のように `-bash: :i: command not found` と表示されています。
最近になってとても気になってきたので解決法が知りたいです

[image: ターミナル]

Comment: `.bashrc`や`.bash_profile`の内容を確認、もしくは差し支えなければ質問の本文に追記してみてください。

Comment: viで編集していてiを押していたのに気づかずに保存した...とか

Comment: ありがとうございました.bash_profileを確認したらiが書き込まれていました

Comment: 自己解決した場合は、自分自身で回答を書き、その回答を承認して下さい。詳しくは[「自分の質問に回答できますか?」](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)をご覧下さい。

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` を確認したら余計な `i` が書き込まれていたのが原因のようです。

---

*この投稿は [@清水幸佑 さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/40110/%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%83%9f%e3%83%8a%e3%83%ab%e8%b5%b7%e5%8b%95%e3%81%ae-bash-i-command-not-found%e3%81%ae%e8%a7%a3%e6%b1%ba#comment40724_40110) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*